# High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-imageview, out-of-memory

I am developing an application for the Galaxy S4.
One of the requirements of the application is having a SplashScreen containing an Image of **1920x1080** pixels. Its a high quality .jpeg image and the size of the Image is about **2 Megabytes**.

The problem is that I am getting an **OutOfMemoryError** as soon as I start the Application. I am quite stunned that this already happens with an image of just 2 megabyte in size? **How can I fix this problem and display the image?**

> Changing the dimensions or the size of the image is not an option.

SplashScreen.java

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 2000;
private boolean isBackPressed = false; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    Handler h = new Handler();

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // check if the backbutton has been pressed within the splash_duration
            if(!isBackPressed) { 

                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Splashscreen.this.startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.short_fade_in, R.anim.short_fade_out);
            }       

            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DURATION);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    isBackPressed = true;
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

And the splashscreen.xml

```
    <ImageView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ivSplashScreenImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/high_res_splashscreen_image"/>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

Sometimes, (when a lot of device memory is available) the app is able to make it past the splash screen, but then, **the memory consumption of the app is just insane**. **(around 100 megabyte)**. Even though I close the SplashScreen Activity and finish() it, it seems that there is **a reference to the ImageView / the Image kept in memory.**

**How can I reduce the huge memory consumption?**

> When I do not display the splash screen, my app only consumes around 35MB
>   of memory. With the SplashScreen image, its around 100MB.

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: Did you have a lot of image files in your res folder??

Comment: Yes, I have around 40 image files. But they are not very large (just icons most of them), having between 10 and 50kb in size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Three hints which should help you:

1. Use this to load your images, from [Loading Large Bitmaps Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html):

   ```
   public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
           int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

       // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
       final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

       // Calculate inSampleSize
       options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

       // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
       return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
   }

   public static int calculateInSampleSize(
               BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
       // Raw height and width of image
       final int height = options.outHeight;
       final int width = options.outWidth;
       int inSampleSize = 1;

       if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

           // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
           final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
           final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

           // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
           // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
           // requested height and width.
           inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
       }

       return inSampleSize;
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you have only one instance of your `Bitmap` in memory. After displaying it, call `recycle()` and set your reference to `null`. You can use [Memory Allocation Tracker](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html) to see what is allocated. You can also read HPROF files, as suggested in comments.
3. By default `ARGB_8888` pixel format is used, which means 4 bytes per pixel. Very good article: [Bitmap quality, banding and dithering](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/). Your image is JPEG, so it doesn't have transparency, so you are wasting 1 byte on every pixel for alpha channel. It's not very probable, but maybe with acceptable quality you can use even more economical format. [Take](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) a look at them. Maybe `RGB_565` for example. It takes 2 bytes for pixel, so your image would be 50% lighter. You can enable dithering to improve the quality of `RGB_565`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Please take a look at my updated answer and the "Additional Information"

Comment: I set the image resource in the .xml file to "@null" and now load the image like that: "((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSplashScreenImage)).setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.highres, 1920, 1080));" I am now able to get past the splashscreen but my app memory consumption is still around 90MB. (without the splash screen, its 35-40mb)

Comment: In theory, a bitmap of size 1920x1080 should only be about 8MB. Can you take a look at an HPROF dump to make sure you're only allocating one of these bitmaps? Now that you're manually loading the image, you should make sure to recycle it and null your reference to it once the splash screen closes. [Memory Analysis for Android Applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Comment: Sorry, changing the image to compress it is sadly not an option :(
However, recycling did the job. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and the solution is simple. Put your high resolution 1920x1080 px image in the **drawable-nodpi** directory. **The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier** regardless of the current screen's density, which leads to the OutOfMemoryError, so the problem should disappear.

Please check Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Hope it helps.