# OutOfMemory Error when trying to rescale a Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-drawable

Im trying to scale a bitmap to make it fit because some device wont show images > 2048.

I found a solution but the app crashes when I choose/take a pic.

That piece of code: (Inside onActivityResult)

```
currImageURI = data.getData();
                path=(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPhoto=drawableToBitmap(d);
                Bitmap sized = mPhoto;
                if(mPhoto.getHeight()>=2048||mPhoto.getWidth()>=2048){
                sized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPhoto, (int)(mPhoto.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(mPhoto.getHeight()*0.8), false);
                }

                image.setImageBitmap(sized);
```

LogCat:

```
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:466)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at com.example.free.Add.onActivityResult(Add.java:149)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5231)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3172)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3219)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
08-28 22:48:14.873: E/AndroidRuntime(12047):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 149 is:

```
sized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPhoto, (int)(mPhoto.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(mPhoto.getHeight()*0.8), false);
```

Could you tell me what can I do to prevent it from crashing?
Thanks!

**Update:**

App still crashes:

```
08-28 23:24:20.219: W/dalvikvm(16289): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412552a0)   
08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at com.example.free.Add.getResizedBitmap(Add.java:335)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at com.example.free.Add.onActivityResult(Add.java:150)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5231)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3172)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3219)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    08-28 23:18:59.917: E/AndroidRuntime(15286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code:

```
currImageURI = data.getData();
                path=(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPhoto=drawableToBitmap(d);
                Bitmap sized = mPhoto;
                if(mPhoto.getHeight()>=2048||mPhoto.getWidth()>=2048){
                    sized=getResizedBitmap(mPhoto,(int)(mPhoto.getHeight()*0.8),(int)(mPhoto.getWidth()*0.8));
                }

                image.setImageBitmap(sized);
```

Comment: Right above the exception in the log should be a message indicating how large the failing allocation attempt was.  Can you add that to the question (to give a sense of scale)?

Comment: Hmm.  Should look like "Out of memory on a 87396-byte allocation."

Comment: what can I do to fix it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at my related question:

**[High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)**

I recommend that you put your Image into the Drawables folder. From there, **load it with the appropriate size using the code below.** This will reduce the memory usage of your app and will always only use as much memory as needed.

Make sure you have only one instance of your Bitmap in memory. After displaying it, call `recycle()` and set your reference to null.

This is how you could load your images:

```
public  Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight) {

     final float densityMultiplier = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

     int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
     int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

     photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

     return photo;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ImageView.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmap(youroldbitmap, 300));
```

Be aware not to use a too high value for your newHeight and keep in mind the **densityMultiplier**.

Taken from: [Failed binder transaction when putting an bitmap dynamically in a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528735/failed-binder-transaction)

Comment: How can I put the image in my drawables folder? Cant find it.. The image comes from an image chooser or the camera. Can I even do that?

Comment: Have you tried casting your mPhoto.getWidth() and height to (float)?
Like that: getResizedBitmap(mPhoto,(int)((float) mPhoto.getHeight()*0.8f),(int)((float) mPhoto.getWidth()*0.8f));

Comment: sure you can, take a close look at my comment

Comment: But the method does it itself.. doesn't it? `float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;`

Comment: Yes, but if mPhoto.getHeight() returns an Integer value, this calculation will be useless: (int)(mPhoto.getHeight()*0.8), it will always result in mPhoto.getHeight() since 0.8 turns to 1.

Comment: I understand. But what can I do about it? I can change the variables that `getResizedBitmap` gets.. Sorry for not understanding you lol. Is that what I should do?

Comment: See my updated answer, that is what you should do :) Im not sure if that will work, its just an idea that came to my mind.

Comment: It looks weird, but Im trying it now.

Comment: Also im not sure if the factor 0.8 is enough. What if an image with sizes of 5000 x 3000 is resized. It would still be 4000x2400 after resizing.

Comment: It makes a toast "width and height must be >0". Where did that toast come from?! its not even in my code..

Comment: You could also make a logcat output and see what the sizes of your photo are at runtime. (I am talking about the calculated sizes, not the original ones)

Comment: Im sure that the sizes are 100% Ok. the error is within the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36420/discussion-between-philipp-jahoda-and-nirpes)