# Load big Images in Android

Tags: java, android, image

It is known that Android has issues with storing bitmap data in RAM memory. I need to load an image (a photo from 13Mpx camera) on the View and then I need to be able to zoom-in and zoom-out the image. The Image should be mutable. Now it is implemented this way:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options =  new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);
```

When I take a large photo (13 or 8 Mpx) programm crushed with "Out of memory" error. I need some solution for this problem. I need some class that can load and operate (scaling it) with big images. It's needed to be equal or less than API-8.

I tried Universall Image Loader, but it has no scaling option. Does someone know any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)

Answer (score 2):

A bitmap takes up 4 bytes per pixel ==> 13MP equals 52MB of memory.
You should use BitmapFactory.Options to get the size only first. By using `inJustDecodeBounds` you get the Bitmap object with all its meta data, but without the actual image.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

then calculate the scale size that your screen needs:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

and use that to load a scaled version of your bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

This is all explained in the [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library from Square. And [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) for image zooming.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for scaling the bitmap

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                            /*
                             * If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to
                             * subsample the original image, returning a smaller
                             * image to save memory. The sample size is the
                             * number of pixels in either dimension that
                             * correspond to a single pixel in the decoded
                             * bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an
                             * image that is 1/4 the width/height of the
                             * original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any
                             * value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the
                             * decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2,
                             * any other value will be rounded down to the
                             * nearest power of 2.
                             */
                            options.inSampleSize = 2;

                            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

To avoid `java.lang.OutOfMemory` exceptions, check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it, unless you absolutely trust the source to provide you with predictably sized image data that comfortably fits within the available memory. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all for all of ur answers.

I thought that I should use inJustDecodeBounds option and load resized bitmap, but In need a fresh view to this problem of more experienced persons.

I also thought about using Universal Image Loader for loading and caching large images and something like ScaleImageView for Zooming it.

There is [something](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) that can solve my problem. Load bitmap partially.