# Android - With my background image crashes the app EDIT : My solution

Tags: android, image, background, size

the image size is 4 Mb, it's a jpg. I haven't any problem  if i try to change the background with another sample image (with a smaller size , for example the ic_launcher sample).

Should be a problem with a size? 
2667 × 4733 it's the image dimension.

I use a samsung s4 mini for debug, it may be useful.

this is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/mioartista"    
    tools:context="com.example.settingavatar.MyAvatar" >

    <!-- other things -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the error log

```
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.settingavatar/com.example.settingavatar.MyAvatar}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
10-15 10:08:43.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3438):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

EDIT : the solution that i adopted:

I changed the dimension. i make 5 set of image ( for the drawable folders) for every screen density.
" is not useful use a 4mb's image if the device use at least the 50% of the size".

Comment: you should use .png format image. The size is not the problem

Comment: but i use the jpg format in other configuration and i haven't any problem..

Comment: could you try the same with a png image. If still that doesn't work, please post you xml and error logs.

Comment: it is an issue with the size...try to use compressed image

Comment: It is not about png or jpeg. It is about your image's width and height.

Comment: Post your layout code, and the images dimensions in pixels.

Comment: 2667 × 4733 it's the image dimension..

Comment: i adopted an easy solution. see the edit

Answer (score 2):

You said your image has the size of **2667 x 4733 pixels.**
Since this image will be turned into a `Bitmap` when being displayed, this is **too large** (in terms of pixels) and will cause your device to run out of memory.

A 32bit `Bitmap` of that size will use up **50 MB of RAM.**

I recommend to reduce the size of the image drastically and **make use of the different resource folders for image sizes**. `drawable-mdpi`, etc.

Also, you can take a look at this question: **[High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)**

It deals with handling and loading large size images properly.

Comment: i can't reduce the quality of my image, i'll try with the method from the question you've posted

Comment: but, how i get a Resources type? ( in the method decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) ).
i search here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html , but all methods return a int type..

Comment: Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap); Layout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Answer (score 0):

Check name of image. You may not use the name with : uppercase, - , * , and start with number.