# App stops working when adding image to imageButton

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I am trying to make a `ScrollView` with some `ImageButtons`.

If I create it with blank buttons it works great.

My xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainScreen">


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/filtersScroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filtersLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro1"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro2"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro3"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro4"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro5"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro6"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro7"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro8"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>




    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And what I get is:

[image: Emulation picture]

But when I add a picture to the `drawable` folder(don't know if it matters but the picture is 2000x2000) and add it to one of the `ImageButtons` like so:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filtro1"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/smiley" />
```

Not only can I not make the image resize to the size of the button, but the app also stops working as soon as i try to run it.

This is how the preview looks like:

[image: buttonPreview]

What am I missing?
Has it something to do with the size of the source picture?
I mean, I just want it to resize to the size of the button and work.

Also, what happened to the other folders that used to be in `drawable/`? Now you don't have to separate the images according to their size?

Comment: If it is crashing, you need to post the stacktrace so we can see why/where

Answer (score 1):

> Has it something to do with the size of the source picture

Yes. You are using a very high resolution image, and surely it will create problem on different devices (especially on low-end device). You should either use scaled down image, or try scaling through code.

> Now you don't have to separate the images according to their size

No, place images in different drawable folders according to their density (not size)

See below links:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

[High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)