# App force closes while loading gridview activity (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: android, gridview

There is a button in my main activity and when it's clicked, it leads to my GridView activity, but the app force closes.

This is my activity_gridview.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myapps.gridviewexample.GridViewActivity"
android:padding="4dp">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

GridViewActivity.java:

```
package com.myapps.gridviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridview);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        if (gridview != null) {
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new         AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                    GridViewActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position + 1);

                }
            });
        }

    }

    public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dp,
                resources.getDisplayMetrics()
        );
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public int getCount() {
          return images.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return images[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                float w = 100;
                float h = 100;
                int width_pixel = convertDpToPixels(w, GridViewActivity.this);
                int height_pixel = convertDpToPixels(h, GridViewActivity.this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width_pixel, height_pixel));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                imageView.setMaxHeight(60);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

The logcat output:

```
10-07 01:26:05.358 1534-1534/com.myapps.gridviewexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
                                                                              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
                                                                              at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14179)
                                                                              at com.myapps.gridviewexample.GridViewActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(GridViewActivity.java:89)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
                                                                              at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1331)
                                                                              at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:331)
                                                                              at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
                                                                              at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:407)
                                                                              at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1219)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1638)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1422)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried everything but it still force closes
Thanks

Comment: check your images size. maybe it's because they're too big

Comment: @Roish Thank you, It worked, and my problem is almost solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people experiencing such issues with large images, please check the google documentation on [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to learn how to load large images without having **OutOfMemoryError**. Also take a look at [Adam Stelmaszczyk's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror) that fixes the same problem.