# High dpi image drawing performance issues on canvas (android)

Tags: android, canvas, dpi, drawbitmap

I download a image with following properties using AsyncTask and then resize and down sample using the logic in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror). In addition image loaded in ARGB_8888 config to in memory (image is a jpg file).

When I segment this image to small images and draw those segments to a canvas, drawbitmap() is significantly slow.

**Questions**

1. Is 600 dpi the issue?
2. Does'nt the down sampling take care of dpi scaling?
3. What is the best dpi for an app running on phones and tablets.

[image]

Comment: in Android Devices its very devices to device.

Comment: The images are stored in a remote server. Its hard store images for each device dpi. My issue is performance

Comment: so you need to scale image each time according available space in device screen .other wise its leads to OOM Exception.

Comment: Thanks, I do down sampling as mentioned. Dont get OOM issue, the issue is drawbitmap()  is slow.