# How to solve a high resolution image out of memory?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

1. ### Below is the code I use to read my image file when I save my image file using FileProvider:

   ```
   public static Bitmap readBitmapFromIntentReturn(Context context, Intent intentReturn, Uri uri) {
                   try {
                       AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
                       fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

                       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                       options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                       BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

                       options.inSampleSize = SystemFunctions.calculateInSampleSize(options);

                       options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
                       return bitmap;
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               return null;
           }
   ```

### 2. Method use to resize the image before I upload it or other, not sure the size is resize correctly or not:

```
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
                final int reqHeight = 360;
                final int reqWidth = 360;

                final int height = options.outHeight;
                final int width = options.outWidth;
                int inSampleSize = 1;

                if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                        inSampleSize *= 2;
                    }
                }

                Log.d("TestSampleSize", "TestSampleSize : " + String.valueOf(inSampleSize));
                return inSampleSize;
            }
```

Comment: take look ans of [Adam Stelmaszczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod wat u mean duplicate?

Comment: I have done the samplesize alrdy

Comment: when you say "a memory leak happens" do you mean that you get an OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: @lelloman ya, your are right

Comment: OutOfMemoryException does not mean memory leak. in some cases, a memory leak might lead to an OutOfMemoryException but in your case the cause it's probably your image being too big

Comment: @lelloman but y it working for asus Android 5 phone but not working for android 6 Samsung galaxy S6. I have done the samplesize to reduce the size alrdy.

Comment: you probably haven't reduced it enough, without seeing the code it's a wild guess

Comment: @lelloman I will upload the code for the reduce part. can u check for me?